# Print to stdout with space's between result?

Tags: python, stdout

I'm stuck with a little problem, 
I want to print to stdout the results with spaces between them

```
x y
```

my code prints it `(x, y)` because I'm only returning them with comma between them

```
return x, y
```

What do I have to add before printing x and y?

Comment: What language are you using? Whatever it is, you should add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns a tuple. What you see is the standard representation of tuples.

There are different solutions;

1) Assign to two variables and print:

```
x, y = function()
print x, y # in Python 3 use print(x, y)
```

2) In python 3 you can unpack:

```
res = function()
print(*res)
```

3) You can use `format`:

```
res = function()
print '{} {}'.format(res[0], res[1])
# In python 3 also with unpacking; print('{} {}'.format(*res))
```

Note that using `format` probably gives you the most flexibility w.r.t. how the output looks. For instance if the values are floating point numbers. Examples in Python 3:

```
>>> res = (12/7, 7/3)
>>> res
(1.7142857142857142, 2.3333333333333335)
>>> print(*res)
1.7142857142857142 2.3333333333333335
>>> print('{:.3f} {:.3f}'.format(*res))
1.714 2.333
```

Answer (score 1):

You've just printed a python `tuple`:

```
>>> print((x, y))
(x, y)
```

You can `unpack` to get your desired result:

```
>>> print(*(x, y))
x y
```

To use in python 2.x, do `from __future__ import print_function`